# Configuring proxy for Spring boot application for keycloack authentication in local machine

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am facing issue in validating the bearer token passed into the spring boot application running on my local machine which is under corporate proxy. The same configuration works perfectly fine when deployed in application servers. Could anyone please guide to configure proxy for the same. Adding current set of configuration and error log for reference.

**Configuration**

keycloak.realm=${KEYCLOACK_REALM}

keycloak.auth-server-url=${KEYCLOACK_AUTH_URL}

keycloak.ssl-required=external

keycloak.resource=${KEYCLOACK_CLIENT_ID}

keycloak.credentials.secret=${KEYCLOACK_CLIENT_SECRET}

keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true

keycloak.bearer-only = true

**Error Log**

```
2022-02-15 14:31:19.396  WARN 1480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from https://XXXXX.com/auth/realms/Collaboration/.well-known/openid-configuration

java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXX.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:230) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:182) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getRealmInfoUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:246) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:107) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:67) [keycloak-adapter-core-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:154) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-15.0.2.jar:15.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `proxy-url` parameter in your adapter config.
See [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config) for details,